# How do I list all packages installed for a specific architecture?

Tags: apt, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to list all the packages installed for a specific architecture, in this case i386, and if possible, install the package from another, in this case amd64. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To find the packages of architecture `i386`,
you could filter the output of `dpkg -l`,
where lines that start with `ii`,
and column 4 is `i386`:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ && $4 == "i386" { print }'
```

To install the package of the `amd64` architecture,
you could use `:amd64` suffix of the package name with the install command.

Comment: `apt list --installed | awk '$3 == "i386" { print }'` output seems more readable to me

Answer (score -1):

You can use `apt list` as well as `dpkg-query --list` to get installed applications.

Use `man apt` and `man dpkg-query` to find what other functions it has.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. `apt list` lists all packages for all architectures.  `apt list --installed` will go part-way to an answer, listing only installed packages, but how do you list installed packages for just, e.g., `i386` architecture?

Comment: @cjs have you tried the janos answer above? that's better put together than mine and addresses this exact issue?

Comment: Yes. But this is about your answer, not his. If you feel your answer has nothing useful to add, you should delete it. (StackExchange is not about maintaining a history of what people thought and said, but about providing the current best answers to questions.)

Comment: @cjs Have a look at the timestamps of the answer! Mine was there first, and it assumes users know how to use Linux documentation built into the system. I'm not here to spoon-feed answers. I can point people towards the right path and they need to be able to follow that.

Comment: I'm aware of the timestamps, but that's not important. As I said, this is not a "history of what people said and thought" forum, it's an answer board. If your answer doesn't contribute to the _current state_ of the answers to the questions, you should delete it. We don't need a record that someone five years ago had an idea for an answer that's no longer relevant.

Comment: _"I'm not here to spoon-feed answers."_ Then you shouldn't be here at all. The entire _point_ of Stack Exchange is to spoon-feed answers to specific questions, not say "go do your research."